# Retrieve column names and types from SQL Server to DataTable C#

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

What would be the best way of building an empty DataTable based on existing table in SQL server? My current try is this one, which is just retyping this manually, so it is not great, especially for large data sets.

```
private DataTable createEmptyReadingDataTableReadyToSaveToDb()
{
    dtbl.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(string));
    dtbl.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(float));
    dtbl.Columns.Add("Revenue", typeof(float));
    dtbl.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));
    //  etc ....
    return dtbl;
}
```

I read today about schemas, which seem natural for this task. It got me more confused than I thought this would be. Anyways such approach below returns a datatable returning broad set of information about the dataset, but I do not find there accessors to get information about the interesting DataTable (below). Probably I do something wrong.

```
private static DataTable getReadingTableFromSchema()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDbConnnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Readings]";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dtbl = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        return dtbl;
    }
}
```

I could also just try the approach with DataAdapter reading the data, then filling it (basically copying the DataTable) and then deleting all rows to have the table empty - but this would definitely affect the performance. What would be the right solution?

Comment: did you saw my anwer?

Comment: I did. Glauco's answer works well for me. Seems most straightforward for the job.

Comment: Yeah, but in my question my SQL query doesn't bring any data, so its faster, so if you are going to use Glauco's answer, at least change the SQL query.

Comment: the easiest way is to Select * from the table where some value is = to -9999 for example a keyId field or you could lookup how to use `SchemaType.Source`

Comment: Good hint, thank you Alberto, I upvoted your answer. It is interesting that your approach does not load the data. I need to get more in depth with this as some next step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use DataAdapter and fill DataTable with full schema:

```
private static DataTable getReadingTableFromSchema()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDbConnnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Readings]";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        DbDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        da.FillSchema(dtbl, SchemaType.Source);
        return dtbl;
    }
}
```

And, I suggest you to use "using" for command and adapter too

Comment: `DataAdapter` doesnt have overload of `FillSchema` that receives a `DataTable`

Comment: Sure Alberto???? Have you studied a bit before speak?
`/// <summary>
/// Configures the schema of the specified <see cref="T:System.Data.DataTable"/> based on the specified <see cref="T:System.Data.SchemaType"/>.
/// </summary>
public DataTable FillSchema(DataTable dataTable, SchemaType schemaType)`

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar yes, I did, look in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx Did you find any method in DataAdapter ther reiceives two parameters(DataTable and SchemaType) ?

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar This documentation is from `SqlDataAdapter` not from `DataAdapter`, look here [system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro: well, if you create a SqlDataAdapter and refer to a DataAdapter as base class, you have also all SqlDataAdapter Methods. FillSchema with this parameters is a DbDataAdapter method:
// Type: System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter
// Assembly: System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll

Comment: So, DbDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter() allow you tu use FillSchema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99245/discussion-between-glauco-cucchiar-and-alberto-monteiro).

Answer (score 3):

Using a bit of LINQ

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDbConnnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Readings] WHERE 1 = 0", conn).ExecuteReader())
    {
        var dataColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                    .Select(i => new DataColumn(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetFieldType(i)))
                                    .ToArray();

        var dataTable = new DataTable("Readings");
        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(dataColumns);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is very complicated and inaccurate, for example you do not load the primary keys....

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar Why is it complicated? Why is it Inaccurate? He ask for columns **names and types** not for primary keys.